# How to load images from application memory in GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery, android-gridview, android-checkbox

I used this [tutorial](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/) to load image from gallery and show in a grid with with a CheckBox. I want to change this code to load image from `/data/data/com.myexample.myfiles/files/`
How can I achieve it? Please help me.

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class AndroidCustomGalleryActivity extends Activity {

private int count;
private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private String[] arrPath;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,  
     MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
            null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        arrPath[i]= imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
    GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imagecursor.close();

    final Button selectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectBtn);
    selectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i =0; i<len; i++)
            {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]){
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                }
            }
            if (cnt == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please select at least one image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You've selected Total " + cnt + " image(s).",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
            }
        }
    });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = cb.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]){
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id = v.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]), "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
        holder.id = position;
        return convertView;
    }
}
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    int id;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the complete code that can be used to load images from any sdcard folder. I have used the [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library for image loading.

public class GalleryScreenActivity extends SherlockActivity{

```
private DisplayImageOptions options;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
private GridView gridView;
protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Custom);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_screen);

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .build();

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();

    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            startImageGalleryActivity(position);
        }
    });
    gridView.setOnScrollListener(new PauseOnScrollListener(true, true));
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    if(Data.array == null){
        getImageStrings();
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(Data.array.size() == 0)
        gridView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();       
}

public void getImageStrings(){
    File sdDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),Constants.PICTURE_SAVE_FOLDER);

    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.
    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!sdDir.exists()) {
        if (!sdDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "failed to create directory");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SD CARD ERROR: FIX IT AND TRY AGAIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{

        }
    }

    File[] sdDirFiles = sdDir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            return filename.contains(".jpg") || filename.contains(".png");
        }
    });

    String tempUrl;

    if(Data.array == null)
        Data.array = new LinkedList<String>();

    if(sdDirFiles != null)
        for(File singleFile : sdDirFiles)
        {
            tempUrl = singleFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("FILE", "file://"+tempUrl);
            Data.array.add("file://"+tempUrl);
        }
}

private void startImageGalleryActivity(int position) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GalleryDetailScreenActivity.class);
    Data.galleryDetailPosition = position;
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.appear_right, R.anim.hide_left);
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    Data.resetData();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.appear_left, R.anim.hide_right);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.appear_left, R.anim.hide_right);
        break;
    }

    return true;
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(Data.array == null)
            return 0;
        return Data.array.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final FrameLayout imageLayout;
        if(convertView == null)
            imageLayout = (FrameLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery_screen_item, null);
        else
            imageLayout = (FrameLayout) convertView;

        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);

        imageLoader.displayImage(Data.array.get(position), imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted() {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason) {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(GalleryScreenActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        return imageLayout;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`File yourDir = new File("data/data/com.myexample.myfiles/files/");

```
    yourDir.mkdir();
enter code here
    ArrayList<GalleryHelper> dataT = null;

    dataT = new ArrayList<GalleryHelper>();

    for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            imageLoader.displayImage("data/data/com.myexample.myfiles/files" + f.getName(), imgSinglePick);



            GalleryHelper item = new GalleryHelper();
            item.sdcardPath = "data/data/com.myexample.myfiles/files" + f.getName();

            dataT.add(item);
        }
    }
    imgAdapter.addAll(dataT);
```

and my gallery helper class is:

public class GalleryHelper {

```
    public String sdcardPath;
    public File file;
    public boolean isSeleted = false;
```

}